# Як сказати українською "supportive"?

Tags: переклад, from-english

В англійській мові на людину, що вміє вислухати, підтримати, кажуть *supportive*. Чи є в українській мові хороший відповідник цьому слову?

Comment: У словниках [E2U](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=supportive&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) є якісь варіанти, але вони радше технічні, аніж стосуються людини, тож я поки не можу порадити щось окрім «такий, що готовий підтримати». Сподіватимемося, хтось інший щось запропонує пізніше.

Comment: *підтрімуваючі* вже не найкращий варіант? а *утрімуваюші* (ciм'ю тoщo)

Comment: *Василь - справжня людина підтримки.* *Святослав - дуже підтримча людина*.

Comment: @dlatikay, do you mean "підтр**и**му(ва)ючі" and "утр**и**му(ва)ючі"? Well, first of all, _підтримуючі_ seems to mean more "those who are supporting (right now)" than "those who are able to support / tend to support". Second, Ukrainian in general doesn't encourage adjective-like active participles (some speakers consider them all to be a mistake, others tolerate only some of them; some adjective-like active participles are more widely used, others sound really weird; but in general that's "gray area"). But that's just my impression, others may find these words really fitting.

Comment: Такий, що підтримує, прихильний? 
Цілком підходить до "providing encouragement or emotional help".
"those who are able to support / tend to support" - підтримливий? Такий, кому властиво підтримувати?

Не для всіх слів є універсальний переклад.

Comment: Здається, не зовсім дослівний переклад, але, можливо — співчутливий? По визначенню, ці значення перетинаються дуже сильно.

Answer (score 2):

**Турботливий** і **Клієнторієнтований**

При перекладі окремого слова слід завжди виходити з контексту, сфери використання та **як**, **коли**, **до кого/до чого** воно застосоване.

*Професійні стосунки:*

**Клієнторієнтований** – це не нативний український відповідник, але найбільш змістовно передає значення при прямому перекладі. Адже, не зважаючи чи це внутрішній, чи зовнішній клієнт, клієнторієнтація передбачає:

- уважне активне слухання;
- поважне ставлення;
- орієнтацію на потребу клієнта;
- зацікавленість у вирішенні питання;
- надання основного і альтернативного та додаткового способу вирішення проблеми (якщо це можливо);
- отримання згоди клієнта з отриманим рішенням;
- відкритість та доброзичливість.

Може пригадав не все, але основне. Саме такі параметри використовують при оцінюванні якості обслуговування клієнтів (Customer Care) по телефону представниками в колцентрах. I саме якість розмови матиме найбільшу питому вагу при визначенні Customer Satisfaction Level.

[Клієнтоорієнтований підхід](https://ag.marketing/klientoorientovaniy-pidhid/)

*Міжособистісні стосунки:*

**Турботливий** ([Турбота](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0)) -  це той що піклується, який і підтримає, і якщо треба пожурить простими зрозумілими словами саме в той час, коли це потрібно саме тобі.

Для кращого розуміння та щоб відчути різницю перекладемо декілька прикладів:

1. Everybody was being helpful and **supportive** to each other at a very difficult time./ Усі були корисними і **підтримували** один одного у дуже важкі часи.
2. Only in **supportive relationships** can we deal with our personal demons and life disappointments. / Лише в **залежних міжособистісних стосунках** ми можемо мати справу зі своїми індивідуальними демонами та життєвими розчаруваннями.
3. People are **supportive** and encouraging and helpful, so I feel extraordinarily fortunate. / З **зацікавленими** бадьорими надійними людьми я відчуваю себе надзвичайно щасливим.
4. Associate with people who are **mutually supportive** and spend less time with friends or relatives who do not support you. / Спілкуйтеся з людьми, що **про вас піклуються** і проводьте менше часу з друзями чи родичами, якщо вони вас не підтримують.
5. There was a great team spirit and **mutually supportive** atmosphere. / Була чудова командна атмосфера та відчувалася **взаємна підтримка**.
6. When the day of amputation is growing close, **supportive psychotherapy** should be started. / Коли день ампутації наближається, слід починати **допоміжну психотерапію**.
7. Maybe being **emotionally supportive** to others over the last few days has left me drained. / Можливо, що **відчуття емпатії** до оточуючих протягом останніх кількох днів зовсім мене виснажило.
8. How can you **be supportive**, nurturing and loving if you are competing with your own children? / Як можна бути **гарним прикладом**, виховувати і любити, якщо змагатися з власними дітьми?
9. People tend to **be supportive** and understanding, but it is not like somebody has died. / Люди намагаються буди дуже **зичливими** і розуміючими, але не коли хтось помре.(чорний гумор)
10. The heartfelt words point to a man who was **supportive and caring**, but always full of laughter and fun. / Сердечні слова вказують на людину **прихильну та лагідну**, але завжди сповнену сміху та радощів.
11. My children have been very **supportive** and I babysit my grandchildren nearly every day. / Мої діти були дуже **слухняними**, то ж я доглядаю й онуків майже кожен день.
12. She has a loving family, with parents in a committed and **mutually supportive relationship**. / У неї любляча родина з відданими батьками на засадах **взаємної турботи і підтримки**.
13. He and his family were **extremely supportive** of the relationship. / Він та його родичі **"запонадзвичайно допомогли"** нашим стосункам. (жартівливе)
14. However, personal partners and close family remain **supportive**. / Допоки твій особистий партнер та родичі до тебе **небайдужі**.
15. The Macmillan nurse who spoke to me later was **very supportive** and sympathetic. / Медсестра Макміллан, з якою я поспілкувався пізніше, поставилася до мене з **увагою** та співчуттям.
16. Join the group and get to know others in a **warmsupportive atmosphere**. / Приєднуйтесь до групи та знайомтеся з іншими в **теплому дружньому колі**.

Comment: мабуть і досить, але про всяк випадок інші приклади залишу в каментах для самостійного опрацювання
17. My family, who had been so supportive of me, has now turned their backs on me.
18. The guides maintain a safe and supportive atmosphere with plenty of time for relaxing.
19. While generally supportive of my writing projects, Bob thought that this one should go in the garbage.
20. I'd like to thank my family for being really supportive and everybody that made my record with me.

Comment: 21. An earlier study of perceptions of communication competence found that participants linked self-disclosure, supportiveness , and a relaxed style of interaction with effective communication behavior.

22. It appears that some degree of communication and supportiveness exhibited by these mothers during interactions with adolescents had not transferred to adolescents' interactions with best friends.

23. Added to high academic achievement must be the many successful business enterprises clustered supportively around the university.

Comment: 24. One trend revealed by the four surveys is that regard for the supportiveness of local politicians seems to be falling.

25. These two variables, which are presumed to be associated with certain parental practices and characteristics such as warmth, supportiveness, and encouragement of independence, have been found to be correlated with health behaviors.

26. The current study did not support previous research that has suggested that parents of depressed youths are lacking in positive expressions of relatedness or supportiveness of their adolescents' autonomy.

Comment: 27. The party also kept lists of professionals, such as doctors, senior police officers and teachers, who were not identifiable as Labour party members but could be relied on to speak supportively .

28. I am here to tell you what you need to know in order to respond sensitively and supportively to your own introverted family members, friends, and colleagues.

Comment: 29. Children have a great ability and capacity to deal with truth, when it is gently and supportively shared with them.

30. Management and the board are committed to ensuring that the process is managed as sensitively and as supportively as is possible for all our staff and students.

Comment: Yola, допомагайте, дуже цікаві приклади

Answer (score 0):

Тут треба застосувати пункт 2 зі статті [Процесові прикметники в науковій мові](https://r2u.org.ua/node/162). А саме

> Прикметники, що вказують на призначення до дії, переважно творяться додаванням до дієслівної основи суфікса ***-льн-*** (*чита-льн-ий, роздава-льн-ий, фільтрува-льн-ий, гостри-льн-ий, дої-льн-ий*), а прикметники, що означають здатність предмета виконувати дію — передусім додаванням суфікса ***-н-*** до найпродуктивнішої в науковій мові дієслівної твірної основи із суфіксом ***-ува-*** (*гарт-ува-ти — гарт-івн-ий, руйн-ува-ти — руйн-івн-ий.* У цих дієсловах ***-ів-*** — це трансформ суфікса основи ***-ува-***, коли до нього приєднують суфікс ***-н-***, пор. також пан-ува-ти — пан-ів+н(ий), кер-ува-ти — кер-ів+н(ий) (від суфікса ***-ува-*** відтинаємо кінцевий голосний ***а***, а звук ***у*** чергуємо з ***і***: *гарт-ув(а)-ти — гартівний*).

А саме, якщо йдеться про терапію призначену для підтримки пацієнта, то кажема *підтримувальна терапія*, а якщо кажемо про людину, яка здатна підтрим-ува-ти інших, якій властиво це робити, то кажемо ***підтримівна** людина*.